# Change HTML5 Canvas size via dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am looking for some good guidance. I need to have specific Canvas sizes from a drop down list. 
This is probably a beginner question but I'm new to JavaScript (which I know is not the same as Java) hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. 
Below is what I have so far. as you can see its HTML calling for a possible script by the name signs_7x10 ...etc. If more code is needed I can supply it no problem. 
But getting the canvas to re-size when an option is changed is what I'm looking for. If I'm not mistaken `7x10` turns into `7000px X 10000px`.

Thanks Again for any help!

```
</li> 
<li> 
<a href="#">Canvis Size</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_7x10');" href="#">7"x10"...</a><canvas width="500" height="500"> 
</canvas></li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_10x14');" href="#">10"x14"...</a>     </li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_12x18');" href="#">12"x18"</a></li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_18x25');" href="#">18"x24"...</a>    </li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_2x3');" href="#">2'x3'...</a></li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_2x8');" href="#">2'x8'...</a></li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_3x12');" href="#">3'x12'"...</a>    </li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_4x4);" href="#">4'x4'...</a></li> 
<li><a onclick="call_menu(SIGNS, 'signs_4x8');" href="#">4'x8'...</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: what's the content of the `call_menu()` method and what is the value of `SIGNS`?

Comment: It is not recommended that you call event handlers from inline HTML code (onclick=""). You should obtain DOM references to the various elements that need to be wired up and do the wiring in JavaScript, not HTML. When done in HTML, you get spaghetti code and your onclick value is executed in a global wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need it to parse the values similar to `signs_7x10`, right?  Not sure if this is entirely what you're after, but you can parse out the xy values with this regex: `/\d+x\d+/`

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[data-size]'), function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    call_menu('???', this.getAttribute('data-size'));
  });
});

function call_menu(ಠ_ಠ, size){
    var element = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var dimensions = size.match(/\d+x\d+/).toString().split('x');
    element.width = dimensions[0] * 1000;
    element.height = dimensions[0] * 1000;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
<li><a data-size="signs_7x10" href="#">7"x10"...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_10x14" href="#">10"x14"...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_12x18" href="#">12"x18"</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_18x25" href="#">18"x24"...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_2x3" href="#">2'x3'...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_2x8" href="#">2'x8'...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_3x12" href="#">3'x12'"...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_4x4" href="#">4'x4'...</a></li> 
<li><a data-size="signs_4x8" href="#">4'x8'...</a></li> 
</ul>

<canvas width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should not be using inline event wiring, but rather, you should use the DOM Standard of:

```
 element.addEventListener("eventName", callbackFunction);
```

Also, it seems that a dropdown list would better serve your needs, rather than multiple hyperlinks.

Please see this fiddle for a working solution that follows best practices:  https://jsfiddle.net/g7ysab0y/12/